# Align DIV's based on parent DIV width dynamic float

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this question: How to change assign dynamic float to a random div's ....

here is the scenario:
I have a "template" to display data from a SQL...
so here is the basic template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="contentData">
    <div class="imageItem>
     <img src="myimage/<?php echo $pathsIMG.'.jpg'; ?> />
       <div class="hoverData">
         <div class="hoverContainerData>
            <div class="moreClasses">More div's that contain the related information</div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div> </div> </div>
```

So until now everything is "ok" but what I would like to get is the following effect:

Actual efect:
[image: You can see the problem on the last div]

What I want:
[image: As you can see all child divs are align and not over flowing outside the current content div...]

So how can get that effect for the child div's to align depending on the position of the parent div...

### Thank you.

I should have explained this at the beginning sorry...
I have a foreach before i dump the data..
and I have a single block that repeat it self using the foreach with array data

so what I did was to add a counter
The following is not the actual code but to give you an idea...

```
$sc = 1;
foreach ( -ARRAY- ) {
<!-- div's to display my template -->
<div> Data </div>
<!-- End data dump with template -->
}
```

So what I did was to add an if with the counter so i can get a different class

```
<!-- div's to display my template -->
<div <?php if($sc=4){echo 'class="cols_'.$sc; $sc=1;}else {echo 'cols_'.$sc; $sc++ ?>> Data </div>
<!-- End data dump with template -->
```

that way i get cols_1, cols_2, cols_3, now that I have this classes I can style each one as I like and positioning them anywhere I want...
Since I only need 3 classes I think this is the best way to do it, it might not be the best way, but it works for me...

thank you all....

Comment: How do you feel about JavaScript / jQuery ?

Comment: I have already some problems dealing with a few jQuery... but I can deal with one more... I already have jquery from google... and a few others for different effect, but please, if you have some, share it, thank you...

Comment: Please include the CSS, and example HTML.  Otherwise someone can't test their code, and know it works for you.  From your provided HTML, it looks like there's one item per `.row`, which is confusing.  Is that true?

Comment: We need the complete picture, that is the rendered HTML, not PHP, and your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Float the containing divs and give them a relative position. Then give the hover div an absolute position of left:0px

```
<div class="row">
<div class="contentData" style="float:left;position:relative;">
<div class="imageItem">
 <img src="myimage/img.jpg' width="100" height="40" style="width:100px;height:40px;" />
   <div class="hoverData">
     <div class="hoverContainerData" style="position:absolute;left:0px;width:200px;background-color:red;">
        <div class="moreClasses">More div's that contain the related information</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="contentData" style="float:left;position:relative;">
<div class="imageItem">
 <img src="myimage/img.jpg' width="100" height="40" style="width:100px;height:40px;" />
   <div class="hoverData">
     <div class="hoverContainerData" style="position:absolute;left:0px;width:200px;background-color:yellow;">
        <div class="moreClasses">More div's that contain the related information</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="contentData" style="float:left;position:relative;">
<div class="imageItem">
 <img src="myimage/img.jpg' width="100" height="40" style="width:100px;height:40px;" />
   <div class="hoverData">
     <div class="hoverContainerData" style="position:absolute;left:0px;width:200px;background-color:blue;">
        <div class="moreClasses">More div's that contain the related information</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, that didn't worked for me, but, it did gave me an idea... thank you..